# Rails bootstrap clickable row doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I'm triying to clickable row in my Rails app. I used Bootstrap 4.1.3 for create table.

Rails version: 5.2.1

```
<tbody>
    <% @animals.each do |animal| %>
      <tr data-link="<%= animal_path(animal) %>">
        <td><%= image_tag(animal.image.url(:small)) %></td>
        <td><%= animal.name %></td>
        <td><%= animal.birthdate %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

This is my animal.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr[data-link]").click(function(event){
        console.log("click")
        window.location.href = $(this).data("link")
        event.preventDefault();
   });
})
```

But i have a problem. When I open the page first time everything is okay. But if i change page with navbar, i am getting this error. And my clickable code doesn't work. I didn't call anywhere text.replace. This error is getting **prevel.js** I didn't use any prevel.js

[error_photo](https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501346231640)

```
Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: text.replace is not a function
```

When i reload the page again everything is okay.

I haven't find a solution. What is a problem?

Comment: please post the code from the navbar where you are calling `text.replace`

Comment: I didn't call anywhere **text.replace** I edited my question and i added error picture. Can you check question please.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the turbolinks gem? if so, change your script to:

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr[data-link]").click(function(event){
        console.log("click")
        window.location.href = $(this).data("link")
        event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
})
```

Or disable turbolinks if you don't want it.

Comment: I didn't think before. It's working now. Thank you so much ^^